# Good map search method

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, search

I want to implement search on my website.
I use mongodb to store events that user have created.

I already have google map on the website and I want the user to search events by moving on map.
I know how to get bounds and search mongodb with spatial queries.

The problem is I don't want to overflow my server with important bounds queries.

For now if a users set the minimum zoom, he will get all the events stored in the database.
How could I do to limit this, without just limiting zoom ?

Comment: Couldn't you limit the number of results for each query? Link db.test.find().limit(10). If the user wants more, pass the offset to the server and use skip. db.test.find().skip(100).limit(10)

Comment: Yes I've already limited number of result. I think i'm gonna code a kind of timer, if the user doesn't touch the map for a moment after a move, i will send new quesries with offset in a certain interval.